# Swift: Ist there any way using @AppStorage with @Observable?

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

I‘d like to store my user defaults in a class. With the old Swift data flow it was possible to use it in a class. Now, with the new system (Xcode 15, Beta 2), it doesn’t work anymore. Is there any way to use it? Maybe a workaround?

This is how it worked before:

```
import SwiftUI

class UserInfo: ObservableObject {

@AppStorage("username") var username: String = ""

}
```

And now I want to use the new system:

```
import SwiftUI

@Observable class UserInfo {

@AppStorage("username") var username: String = ""

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 8):

Using `@AppStorage ...` in `class UserInfo: ObservableObject` works well at updating the `UserDefaults`. It is not `observed` as when you use `@Published var ...` variables.

Similarly to use the equivalent in the new `@Observable`, try using:

```
 @Observable class UserInfo { 

       @ObservationIgnored @AppStorage("username") var username: String = ""

 }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for the simple and consistent solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way while @AppStorage is incompatible with @Observable.

```swift
@Observable
final class SomeClass {
    var name: String {
        get {
            access(keyPath: \.name)
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") ?? ""
        }
        set {
            withMutation(keyPath: \.name) {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-observation-revised/63757/112).

Comment: While the next answer is more elegant, this one retains observability.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone would prefer using a Swift Macro for the above code, [this repo by davidsteppenbeck](https://github.com/davidsteppenbeck/ObservableUserDefault) could help.

It's quite simple to use it:

```swift
import ObservableUserDefault

@Observable
final class StorageModel {
    @ObservableUserDefault
    @ObservationIgnored
    var name: String
}
```

... or ...

```swift
import ObservableUserDefault

@Observable
final class StorageModel {
    @ObservableUserDefault(.init(key: "NAME_STORAGE_KEY", defaultValue: "John Appleseed", store: .standard))
    @ObservationIgnored
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, this Swift Package works super well and is easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers in this post cover, pretty much, all the real uses, but, for the sake of completeness, here’s a variant that uses the `@AppStorage` macro:

```swift
@Observable
class MyModel {
    
    // Externally visible properties
    
    @ObservationIgnored
    var name: String {
        get {
            access(keyPath: \.name)
            return _name
        }
        set {
            withMutation(keyPath: \.name) {
                _name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Internal stored properties
    
    @ObservationIgnored
    @AppStorage("name")
    private var _name: String = "Bob"
    
}
```

Quite verbose, but doesn’t use any external macros and quite easy to extend it to support, say, storing `Codable`.